# How can i compile kobotoolbox/odk collect in Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, odk

I have a basic understanding of git and i have been using Github and Bitbucket
I was trying to get the source from 
[Github](https://github.com/kobotoolbox/collect)! 
 but i do not understand the given instructions in the read me.I have done my [research](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/opendatakit-developers) , but i have found no solutions.

Things i have tried include

1. Importing the project into Android Studio
2. Copy pasting the source code into a new project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the process, Here are the steps if any one requires them

1. Launch Git console
2. Make a new directory `mkdir [directory name]`
3. Change to that directory `cd [directory name]`
4. Clone the repos

`git clone https://github.com/opendatakit/google-play-services.git`
 `git clone https://github.com/opendatakit/collect.git`
 `git clone https://github.com/opendatakit/gradle-config.git`

5. These will automatically set these projects to the tip of master. 
   Now change gradle-config to be at the version required by collect/settings.gradle  (e.g., 40)

`cd gradle-config` `git checkout 40`

(4) Open Android Studio ...New /Import Project...       collect/build.gradle

Comment: I can't seem to find any version number in collect/settings.gradle